# How to generate a random five digit number Java

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: generating random number in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

I need a little help.

What code would I use to create a random number that is 5 digits long and starts with either 1 or 2?

In order to use as a company employees ID?

Comment: RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Depending on how you approach the problem something like that:

```
public int gen() {
    Random r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    return 10000 + r.nextInt(20000);
}
```

Or something like that (you probably want the instantation of the *Random* object of of the method but I just put it here for simplicity) :

```
public int gen() {
    Random r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    return ((1 + r.nextInt(2)) * 10000 + r.nextInt(10000));
}
```

The idea is that *1 + nextInt(2)* shall always give 1 or 2.  You then multiply it by 10000 to satisfy your requirement and then add a number between [0..9999].

Here's are some example output:

```
14499
12713
14192
13381
14501
24695
18802
25942
21558
26100
29350
23976
29045
16170
23200
23098
20465
23284
16035
18628
```

Comment: Please do not use this method. In my experience this is not generating random numbers. Refer to this thread for reliable solutions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java