# Generating a Random Pin of 5 Digits

Tags: java

I would like to generate Unique Pins based on a random number I have found this on Stack Overflow [How to generate a random five digit number Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815196/how-to-generate-a-random-five-digit-number-java). That Question uses time to generate the numbers so therefore you get a lot of duplicates.

Here is my code

```
public int createRandomPin() {
    int k = random.nextInt(Integer.SIZE);
    k = (k + 1) * 9999;
    if (9999 > k || k > 99999) {
        //then regenerate 
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}
```

My Question

Java Compiler then gives a warning missing "return". As well I need to restructure the code so that if it isn't a 5 digit pin it generates again before it "returns k".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest to generate random number using SecureRandom class and then as it needs to be of 5 digits create a random number between 0 and 99999 using random.nextInt(100000) , here 0 is inclusive and 100000 is exclusive and then format it into 5 digit by appending zero.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
int num = random.nextInt(100000);
String formatted = String.format("%05d", num); 
System.out.println(formatted);
```

I hope this solves your problem

Edit: This post incorrectly said 10,000, has been edited to say 100,000

Comment: If you use String.format,then everytime you will get 5 digit number,i.e. zero will be appended if the number is having fewer digits than five.

Comment: I have tried your way of generating pins far better than the other ways. I need to add something which can test whether or not the pin is of 5 digits if it isn't it regenerates.Else it returns it.

Comment: @User In my case always number generated will be of 5 digits as "0" will be padded if it is less than 5 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.SIZE` yields the number in bits of the `int` data type. This nothing has to do with the range span for a random value.

Using it as the argument of `Random.nextInt` doesn't make any sense (actually it generates a random value in range `[0,32)`).

Just generate a int `value = random.nextInt(100000)` so that you will obtain a value in `[0,99999]`.

Now your definition of 5 digits pin is not precise, `40` could be interpreted as `00040` so it's still 5 digits if you pad it. You must take this thing into account, since forcing 5 "visible" digits implies generating a number in range `[10000,99999]` but this is just an awkward solution.

Answer (score 0):

`RandomUtils.randomNumeric(int count)` or `RandomUtils.randomNumeric(int inLength, int maxLength)` from apache common lang3 can also be used for the same purpose.